# Decoding failed while fetching API | Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, alamofire

When I print self.getTokenBalancesModel it gives me the error that it failed Decoding. What am I doing wrong?

**ViewModel**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

final class TokenBalancesClassAViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var getTokenBalancesModel: [GetTokenBalancesItemsModel] = [GetTokenBalancesItemsModel]()
    
    func makeApiRequest() {
        let url = "https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/1/address/0x726A73081C4134b2f639b821377482c71864EBc8/balances_v2/?&key=ckey_4eeea29a22c14701a9844f01151"
        
        AF.request(url).responseData(completionHandler: { data in
            if let apiJsonData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(TokenBalancesModel.self, from: data.data!){
                self.getTokenBalancesModel = apiJsonData.data.items
                print(self.getTokenBalancesModel)
            } else {
                print("Decoding failed")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Models**

```
struct TokenBalancesModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let data: TokenBalancesDataModel
    let error: Bool
}

struct TokenBalancesDataModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let address: String
    let quote_currency: String
    let items: [TokenBalancesItemsModel]
}

struct TokenBalancesItemsModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let contract_name: String
    let contract_ticker_symbol: String
//    let logo_url: String
    let balance: Int
    let quote_rate: Float
    let quote: Float
}
```

it's clearly in the decoding section:

```
if let apiJsonData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(TokenBalancesModel.self, from: data.data!){
```

where I'm making the mistake, but I don't see why

Comment: You can use `responseDecodable` to decode your types directly, no need to do it manually.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you write an example? @JonShier

Comment: Instead of using `responseData`, use `responseDecodable`.

Comment: @JonShier if substitute it, it says: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Comment: Yes, you need to actually use it correctly. In your case, `responseDecodable(of: TokenBalancesModel.self)` or similar. You can read more in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `try?` you'll get more information if you catch the error.

When debugging a common catch chain I'll use is

```swift
} catch let DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context) {
    print(context)
} catch let DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, context) {
    print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch let DecodingError.valueNotFound(value, context) {
    print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch let DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context) {
    print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

By using the above you'll see the following error

> Type 'Int' mismatch: Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.
> codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "items", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "balance", intValue: nil)]

Which will draw your attention to the `TokenBalancesItemsModel.balance` field being the incorrect type.

Comment: jojojo debugging to another lvl Thank you! I'll implement this from now on :) Also that's weird, in the documentation they have it as integer hm.. anyway, many thanks!

Comment: in my own personal experience I've found that sometimes APIs will return the type they specify as a different type, I've had many bool values as ints or strings, or ints in strings. worse is when an API will return different types for different entities. unfortunately it just means we have to convert it to how we want it in the clients.

Comment: I tested in Playgrounds, but here is a Gist with an example solution for decoding the string to an int without having to write the entire decoding init for your types by hand. https://gist.github.com/theoriginalbit/2b184d4e94ed3d46e5048e769b0b196b

EDIT: I see you removed your message, hopefully that means you worked it out 

Answer (score 1):

use this, note the optionals:

```
struct TokenBalancesModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let data: TokenBalancesDataModel
    let error: Bool
}

struct TokenBalancesDataModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let address: String?
    let quote_currency: String?
    let items: [TokenBalancesItemsModel]
}

struct TokenBalancesItemsModel: Codable, Hashable {
    let contract_name: String?
    let contract_ticker_symbol: String?
//    let logo_url: String
    let balance:  String?    // <-- here no Int
    let quote_rate: Float?
    let quote: Float?
}
```

Comment: why a String with optional if the value is a number (int)?

Comment: balance is not an number, it is a string. Let me know if this does not work for you. "balance" : "52315554326750453", is a string, if it was a number it would be "balance" : 52315554326750453.  without the quotes.

Comment: yep, those optionals did the trick, how do I unwrap that later?  I tried: `print(self.getTokenBalancesModel!)` but it complains, it says: `Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '[TokenBalancesItemsModel]'`

Comment: as you can see: "let items: [TokenBalancesItemsModel]" is not an optional. Do not unwrap it.